# Задача по sql, странное поведение case when

Tags: sql

При решении одной из задач по sql на сайте https://www.sql-ex.ru/ в базе данных "Компьютерная фирма" решение заключалось в применении условий с помощью `case when`.
Меня интересует, почему данное условие не сработало, т.е. решение не прошло проверку на дополнительной базе?

```
select p.maker,case when max(case when t.price is null then 0 else 1 end)=1 then max(t.price) end as m_price from product p...`
```

хотя результат правильный,
 а это решение правильное:

```
select p.maker,case when max(case when t.price is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 then max(t.price) end as m_price from product p...
```

т.е. разница всего лишь здесь:
 `case when max(case when t.price is null then 0 else 1 end)=1 then max(t.price) end`
 `case when max(case when t.price is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 then max(t.price) end`    - второе условие правильный результат
ведь по идее не имеет значение где будет стоять 1 и 0 в условии `then и else`?
или нужно показать всю задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница есть

```
max(case when t.price is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 - выполнится только если все t.price is NOT null 

max(case when t.price is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1 - выполнится если хотя бы один t.price is NOT null
```

аналог Вашего второго должен вы глядеть как

```
min(case when t.price is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1 - выполнится только если все t.price is NOT null
```